# >= Message Box sequence not working properly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a messagebox pop up when "Trade-in Value" >= "Price." If I enter Trade-in Value:2000 and Price:12,000. The messagebox comes up, when clearly that should not be happening. After testing a bunch of numbers, it seems like the form doesn't like the number "2" in either text box. The second block is where I have my code that does not work.
I am fairly new to coding and this is my first post, taker easy boy/girls.

Entered numbers/Form

[image: Entered numbers/Form]

Message Box error

[image: Message Box error]

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GBTradeIn.Enabled = False
    TxtTradeIn.Enabled = False
    RBStandard.Checked = True
    RBExcellent.Checked = True
End Sub
Private Sub CBTradeIn_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CBTradeIn.CheckedChanged
    GBTradeIn.Enabled = True
    TxtTradeIn.Enabled = True
    If CBTradeIn.Checked = (False) Then
        GBTradeIn.Enabled = False
        TxtTradeIn.Enabled = False
        RBExcellent.Checked = True
        TxtTradeIn.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub BtnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCalculate.Click
    Try
        If CBTradeIn.Checked = (False) Then
            TxtTradeIn.Text = 0
        End If
        If RBExcellent.Checked Then
            TxtTradeInAllowance.Text = FormatCurrency(TxtTradeIn.Text * 1)
        ElseIf RBGood.Checked Then
            TxtTradeInAllowance.Text = FormatCurrency(TxtTradeIn.Text * 0.9)
        ElseIf RBFair.Checked Then
            TxtTradeInAllowance.Text = FormatCurrency(TxtTradeIn.Text * 0.8)
        ElseIf RBPoor.Checked Then
            TxtTradeInAllowance.Text = FormatCurrency(TxtTradeIn.Text * 0.7)
        End If
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Enter valid Trade-In value")
    End Try
    Dim Exterior As Decimal
    Dim Accessories As Decimal
    If CBPremiumStereo.Checked And CBLeatherInterior.Checked And CBGPS.Checked Then
        Accessories = 3154.4
    ElseIf CBPremiumStereo.Checked And CBLeatherInterior.Checked Then
        Accessories = 1413.17
    ElseIf CBPremiumStereo.Checked And CBGPS.Checked Then
        Accessories = 2166.99
    ElseIf CBGPS.Checked And CBLeatherInterior.Checked Then
        Accessories = 2728.64
    ElseIf CBPremiumStereo.Checked Then
        Accessories = 425.76
    ElseIf CBLeatherInterior.Checked Then
        Accessories = 987.41
    ElseIf CBGPS.Checked Then
        Accessories = 1741.23
    End If
    If RBStandard.Checked = True Then
        Exterior = 0
    ElseIf RBPearlized.Checked = True Then
        Exterior = 345.72
    ElseIf RBCustom.Checked = True Then
        Exterior = 599.99
    End If
    TxtAccessoriesAndFinish.Text = FormatCurrency(Accessories + Exterior)
    Try
        Dim total As Decimal
        Dim TradeIn As Decimal
        Dim AccessoriesandExterior As Decimal
        Dim Subtotal As Decimal
        total = TxtPrice.Text
        TradeIn = TxtTradeInAllowance.Text
        AccessoriesandExterior = TxtAccessoriesAndFinish.Text
        TxtSubtotal.Text = FormatCurrency(total + AccessoriesandExterior - TradeIn)
        Subtotal = TxtSubtotal.Text
        TxtSalesTax.Text = FormatCurrency((Subtotal + TradeIn) * 0.08)
        TxtAmountDue.Text = FormatCurrency(Subtotal + TxtSalesTax.Text)
    Catch
        TxtAccessoriesAndFinish.Text = ""
        TxtAmountDue.Text = ""
        TxtTradeIn.Text = ""
        TxtSubtotal.Text = ""
        TxtSalesTax.Text = ""
        TxtPrice.Text = ""
        TxtTradeInAllowance.Text = ""
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid price")
    End Try
```

>

```
    If TxtTradeIn.Text >= TxtPrice.Text Then
            TxtAccessoriesAndFinish.Text = ""
            TxtAmountDue.Text = ""
            TxtTradeIn.Text = ""
            TxtSubtotal.Text = ""
            TxtSalesTax.Text = ""
            TxtPrice.Text = ""
        TxtTradeInAllowance.Text = ""

        MessageBox.Show("Trade in value can't be higher than or equal to price")
        End If
        If CBTradeIn.Checked = (False) Then
        TxtTradeIn.Text = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

>

```
Private Sub BtnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClear.Click
    TxtAccessoriesAndFinish.Text = ""
    TxtAmountDue.Text = ""
    TxtTradeIn.Text = ""
    TxtSubtotal.Text = ""
    TxtSalesTax.Text = ""
    TxtPrice.Text = ""
    RBStandard.Checked = True
    RBExcellent.Checked = True
    CBPremiumStereo.Checked = False
    CBLeatherInterior.Checked = False
    CBGPS.Checked = False
    CBTradeIn.Checked = False
    TxtTradeInAllowance.Text = ""

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Did you put the comma in 12,000? That will mess things up. There are several ways to handle this. You could convert or cast you strings, which .Text properties are to numbers or strip out any commas before trying the comparison/

Comment: @Mary No commas were used when entering in 12000 into the text box. Are you saying convert .text to an integer? There are also two pictures I uploaded on the main question.

Comment: `If TxtTradeIn.Text >= TxtPrice.Text Then (...)`. What are you comparing here? Set `Option Strict On` and compare the value Types you actually want to compare. Use `.TryParse()` when dealing with user input (you probably need `Decimal.TryParse()`, here.

Comment: As implied by @Jimi, you are comparing two `String` values, not numbers.  Just as any `String` that starts with "A" is 'less than' and `String` that starts with "B", so any `String` that starts with "1" is 'less than' any `String` that starts with "2".  If you want to do a numerical comparison then compare numbers, not text that contains digit characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
If TxtTradeIn.Text >= TxtPrice.Text Then
```

use

```
If CDec(TxtTradeIn.Text) >= CDec(TxtPrice.Text) Then
```

`CDec()` converts the text inside the brackets to a decimal, allowing you to do numerical comparison rather than string comparison.

However, you must be careful: `CDec()` will return an error if you try to convert a non decimal to a decimal, such as a string, so you will have to check that the user has entered a valid decimal in the textboxes

Comment: Thanks for the help Mr. Popo

Comment: No problem, happy to help.